# How to define a dynamic mixin or function name in SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins, dynamic-function

I want to dynamically create mixins in SASS, named after each item in the list, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried this but I get an error:

```
$event-icons: fair, concert, art-show, conference, dance-show, film, party, festival, theatre, launch
@each $event-icon in $event-icons
  @mixin event-icon-#{$event-icon}
    background-position: -($event-icon-width * $i) 0
```

Error:

```
Invalid CSS after "": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#{$event-icon}"
```

Is this usage not supported by SASS? I couldn't find anything in the manual about it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a `@mixin` in this situation? See my answer below

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Variable interpolation in @mixins does not appear to be supported currently.**

The SASS documentation calls this `#{} interpolation` and [describes it like this](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

> Interpolation: #{}
>
> You can also use SassScript variables in **selectors** and **property names** using #{} interpolation syntax:

```
$name: foo;
$attr: border;
p.#{$name} {
  #{$attr}-color: blue;
}
```

Per the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_), interpolation of variable names only appears to be supported for selectors and property names, and not for `@mixin`s. If you'd like that feature, you may want to [file an Issue](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues) for it, although [this one](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/626) may already be tracking what you're describing.

**Edit:**
Are you sure you need to use a `@mixin` to accomplish the kind of styling you're talking about? Could you just use a selector with interpolation? For example, would this work:

```
$event-icons: fair, concert, art-show, conference, dance-show, film, party, festival, theatre, launch
@for $i from 1 to length($event-icons)
  $event-icon: nth($event-icons, $i)
  .event-icon-#{$event-icon}
    background-position: -($event-icon-width * $i) 0
```

Comment: I actually ended up using a selector, but that doesn't work for all situations. I want to be independent of selectors and have mixins that could easily be used other places, also with pseudo-selectors like :hover on links (which wrap the icon).

Comment: It is better to use `through` in the for-loop declaration in this case. Otherwise, the last element (`launch`) won't be counted.

Answer (score 21):

As of this moment (March 30th, 2014), **[Chris Eppstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41221/chriseppstein)** still refuses to implement dynamic mixins. See **[issue 857](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/857)** and **[issue 626](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/626)** on Github.

I've been trying to convince Chris that this feature is quite essential for Sass to unleash its true power... and I'm not the only one there.

If you agree that this is an important feature, please go to **[issue 857](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/857)** and **[issue 626](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/626)** and address this problem yourself. The more of us provide a use case for this feature, the more likely we'll be able to convince Chris and/or one of the other lead developers.

---

**UPDATE**: In 2016, Eppstein did end up implementing this feature due to the number of requests for it. However, today (mid 2018), these changes still haven't been merged into the main branch and thus remain unavailable in the sass release. See
[**issue 2057**](https://github.com/sass/sass/pull/2057).

Comment: +1 As I said in the thread, it's a good feature -- I actually need it at work. As soon as the Sass feature freeze is over we'll be able to work on it. I don't know why you're trying to lobby for a feature that we've already agreed is a fine idea. Instead, maybe work on a pull request so it gets done sooner?

Comment: @chriseppstein I'm not very fluent in Ruby, I'm afraid. I'm more of a PHP/MySQL, HTML/CSS/JS & XML/Json kind of guy. Anyway, you'll notice that this answer was posted on March 30th, 2014. Back then, you were still véry reluctant to add this feature. I'm glad you changed your mind. Maybe my lobbying paid off in the end?!? ;-)

Comment: Actually you are correct. I have not yet been convinced that dynamic definition of mixins is a good idea. However the issue you linked to was about including a mixin using a dynamic name. Which I am for. The OP's problem is solved better by accepting an argument to a single mixin instead of defining a unique mixin for each icon.

Comment: @chriseppstein : It would be nice to both define and include a mixin, analogous to dynamically defining and extending placeholders (which is a feature I love). Still, I agree that defining them dynamically is not really an essential feature. Including them dynamically is a far more essential feature IMO (see eg. https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/857#issuecomment-39013579).

Answer (score 9):

The best solution is to implement a single mixin that takes an argument.

```
$event-icons: fair, concert, art-show, conference, dance-show, film, party, festival, theatre, launch
@mixin event-icon($name)
  @if not index($event-icons, $name)
    @error "#{$name} is not an event icon."
  background-position: -($event-icon-width * $i) 0
```