# How to make a mixin with the same name as the value of a variable?

Tags: css, stylus

I have variable and need to construct mixin with its value:

```
$param = 'color';

{$param}() {
  color: green;
}

.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

It's renders as

```
color() {
  color: #008000;
}
.foo {
  color: #f00;
}
```

But I need

```
.foo {
  color: #008000;
}
```

Maybe, I don't know, how to do it right.
How can I get it?

Comment: Are you looking to just pass the variable to the mixin?

Comment: what about .foo { @include color; } ?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, not just inside, in mixin name also.

Comment: @Ser-Gen, Okay that would be `#{}` interpolation syntax. And that doesn't work with mixins unfortunately. See updated answer. Also see.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748937/how-to-define-a-dynamic-mixin-name-in-sass

Comment: @kariem, no, I need variable value in name of mixin. This example is just to demonstrate, not use case.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, my question is about Stylus. But thanks, your answer is interesting. Maybe the same problem in Stylus too.

Comment: Ah, my bad.. I thought you where I asking about SASS. Guess I should have looked at the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got [answer](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues/1631#issuecomment-49024960) from maintainer of Stylus:

> You can do this with define bif and anonymous functions:

```
$param = 'color'

define($param, @() {
  color green
})

.foo
  color red
```