# How to use @each in mix includes in Sass?

Tags: sass, node-sass

I'm trying to dynamically generate my @include and also insert the @content dynamically so I do not have to keep repeating the code ..

However I am getting the following error that is below, and I would like to know what I am doing wrong and if it is possible to do this with includes or I must enter all variable names manually.

```
$ node-sass scss/_sixbase-grid.scss ../app/src/public/css/sixbase-grid.min.css --output-style expanded
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/Users/THIAGOSAAD/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/SIXBASE/PERSONAL PROJECTS/githubcompare/build/scss/_sixbase-grid.scss",
  "line": 40,
  "column": 12,
  "message": "no mixin named media-",
  "formatted": "Error: no mixin named media-\n        on line 40 of scss/_sixbase-grid.scss\n>>   @include media-#{$media-key} {\n\n   -----------^\n"
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**SIXBASE-GRID.SCSS**

```
/*!
 * Sixbase Flexbox v1.0.0 (https://sixbase.tech/)
 * Copyright 2019 Sixbase.
 * Licensed under GNU General Public License v3.0 (https://github.com/sixbase-tech/githubcompare/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@import './mixins/media-queries';

$container-map: (
  flex:   ( display: flex ), 
  inline: ( display: inline )
);

$flex-direction-map: (
  row:            ( flex-direction: row ),
  row-reverse:    ( flex-direction: row-reverse ),
  column:         ( flex-direction: column ),
  column-reverse: ( flex-direction: column-reverse )
);

$media-map: (
  smartphone-xs: ( type: 'xs' ), 
  smartphone-sm: ( type: 'sm' ), 
  tablet-md:     ( type: 'md' ), 
  tablet-lg:     ( type: 'lg' ), 
  desktop:       ( type: 'xl')
);

* {
  &::before,
  &::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}


@each $media-key in $media-map {
  @include media-#{$media-key} {
   @each $display-key, $display-type in $container-map {
       .container-#{map-get($map: $media-key, $key: type )}-#{$display-key} { 
         display: map-get($map: $display-type, $key: display ); 
       }
     }
  }
}
```

**MEDIA_QUERIES.SCSS**

```
$xs-width: 320px;
$sm-width: 576px;
$md-width: 768px;
$lg-width: 992px;
$xl-width: 1200px;

@mixin media-smartphone-xs {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $xs-width) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin media-smartphone-sm {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $sm-width) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin media-tablet-md {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $md-width) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin media-tablet-lg {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $lg-width) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin media-desktop {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $xl-width) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `@include media-#{$media-key} {...}` 'cause you can't use interpolation in `@mixin`. See this post, it is very clear about this *issue*: [How to define a dynamic mixin or function name in SASS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748937/how-to-define-a-dynamic-mixin-or-function-name-in-sass)

So, we have to use another way. A solution could be create a general mixin and work with its arguments. Something like this:

```
@mixin general-media($width){
  @media only screen and (min-width: $width) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

After that, I choose to add your width values in `$media-map` map and use them with that mixin (I tried to use your code):

```
$media-map: (
  smartphone-xs: ( type: 'xs', width: $xs-width ), 
  smartphone-sm: ( type: 'sm', width: $sm-width ), 
  tablet-md:     ( type: 'md', width: $md-width ), 
  tablet-lg:     ( type: 'lg', width: $lg-width ), 
  desktop:       ( type: 'xl', width: $xl-width )
);
```

And this is your loop with some changes:

```
@each $media-key, $media-type in $media-map {
  @include general-media(map-get($media-type, 'width')) {
   @each $display-key, $display-type in $container-map {
       .container-#{map-get($media-type, 'type' )}-#{$display-key} { 
         display: map-get($map: $display-type, $key: display ); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is all code in action:

```
/* MEDIA_QUERIES.SCSS */

$xs-width: 320px;
$sm-width: 576px;
$md-width: 768px;
$lg-width: 992px;
$xl-width: 1200px;

@mixin general-media($width){
  @media only screen and (min-width: $width) {
    @content;
  }
}

/* SIXBASE-GRID.SCSS */

$container-map: (
  flex:   ( display: flex ), 
  inline: ( display: inline )
);

$flex-direction-map: (
  row:            ( flex-direction: row ),
  row-reverse:    ( flex-direction: row-reverse ),
  column:         ( flex-direction: column ),
  column-reverse: ( flex-direction: column-reverse )
);

$media-map: (
  smartphone-xs: ( type: 'xs', width: $xs-width ), 
  smartphone-sm: ( type: 'sm', width: $sm-width ), 
  tablet-md:     ( type: 'md', width: $md-width ), 
  tablet-lg:     ( type: 'lg', width: $lg-width ), 
  desktop:       ( type: 'xl', width: $xl-width )
);

* {
  &::before,
  &::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@each $media-key, $media-type in $media-map {
  @include general-media(map-get($media-type, 'width')) {
   @each $display-key, $display-type in $container-map {
       .container-#{map-get($media-type, 'type' )}-#{$display-key} { 
         display: map-get($map: $display-type, $key: display ); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output:

```
*::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .container-xs-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container-xs-inline {
    display: inline;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .container-sm-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container-sm-inline {
    display: inline;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-md-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container-md-inline {
    display: inline;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-lg-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container-lg-inline {
    display: inline;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container-xl-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container-xl-inline {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```