# How to concatenate Sass @include function

Tags: sass

I Have Variable $direction , $left , $direction

```
$direction == rtl ;
$left:left; 
$right:right;

@if($direction == rtl){
   $left : right;
   $right : left;
}
```

I Want Change In

```
@include border-right-radius(0);
```

as

```
@include border-#{$right}-radius(0);
```

I See Error

I Want Get Result as

```
@include border-left-radius(0);
```

I Know i Can Use

```
@if($direction == rtl){
   @include border-left-radius(0);
}@else{
   @include border-right-radius(0);
}
```

notes
in url [How to define a dynamic mixin or function name in SASS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748937/how-to-define-a-dynamic-mixin-or-function-name-in-sass)
he want create dynamically mixins , put i want retrieve dynamically mixins

Update
I have change in mixins function and retrieve as static mixins , It seems more logical And a shortcut to time

Comment: Do you want to concatenate a string as a SASS @include function name?

Comment: yes alexis
i want reslut @include border-left-radius(0);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a dynamic mixin or function name in SASS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748937/how-to-define-a-dynamic-mixin-or-function-name-in-sass)

Comment: @ReSedano
notes i url he want create dynamically mixins , put i want retrieve dynamically mixins

Comment: @HosamElzagh Sure, I noticed that, but my comment don't change: you can't use interpolation with a mixin. That answer is very clear about that and also provides an explanation link where you can find every information about how you can use interpolation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation. So for me this is a duplicate 'cause the answer you are looking for is the same: you can't do this. I'm sorry ;-)

Comment: @ReSedano thanks for replay , I have change in mixins function and retrieve  as static mixins , It seems more logical And a shortcut to time