# Mixin calling function, used in variable SCSS

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have a SCSS file containing font mixins, e.g:

```
@mixin font1 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
}
%font1 {
    @include font1
}
```

I want to include this font as a default variable in another mixin. I've tried multiple variations but I cannot get the SCSS to compile as it does not like `%font1`:

```
@mixin mainHeader($font: %font1) {
  @extend #{$font};
  ...
}

@mixin mainHeader($font: #{%font1}) {
  @extend #{$font};
  ...
}
```

Is it not possible to include a mixin as a default variable for use in `@extend`?

Answer (score 0):

Here `%font1` is a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors), not a mixin. If you want to use it as a variable to extend it you need to define it as a string:

```
@mixin mainHeader($font:"%font1") {
  @extend #{$font};
}
```

Currently, mixins [can't be invoked dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22738882/9718056).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, and throws the error `SassError: Expected identifier` - it doesn't like the use of `#{$font}`? I tried using `@include` instead of `@extend` (I actually need to do this because I need to use a media query) and neither work

Comment: @user1486133 I tested the code on SassMeister and it works fine. What are you using to compile your code? `@include` can't work with a variable, please refer to the link in my answer.